# Use Woocommerce filter value as Redux Framework option

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redux-framework

I would like to use an Array returned by a Woocommerce filter as a value in a Redux Framework field. I do understand the filter returns after the Woocommerce plugin has loaded. I've tried to move the Redux::setSection method inside the filter function but it appears the section method is not called in that case. Any suggestions?

```
$statuses;
    add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {


$statuses = $order_statuses;

    return $order_statuses;
}



/*Need to pass $statuses to the Redux::setSection*/

Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Text Options', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( 'For full documentation on this field, visit: ', 'redux-framework-demo' ) . '<a href="http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/text/" target="_blank">http://docs.reduxframework.com/core/fields/text/</a>',
    'id'         => 'opt-text-subsection',
    'icon'  => 'el el-home',
    'subsection' => false,
    'fields'     => array(


        array(
            'id'=>'multi-text',
            'type' => 'multi_text',
            'title' => __('Multi Text Option - Color Validated', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'validate' => 'color',
            'subtitle' => __('If you enter an invalid color it will be removed. Try using the text "blue" as a color.  ;)', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'desc' => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo')
        ),
        array(
            'id'       => 'opt-select',
            'type'     => 'select',
            'title'    => __('Select Option', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
            'subtitle' => __('No validation can be done on this field type', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            'desc'     => __('This is the description field, again good for additional info.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
            // Must provide key => value pairs for select options
            'options'  => $statuses,
            'default'  => '2',
        )
    )
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Redux data field. You can make a custom callback, and the data will always be up to date.

https://docs.redux.io/configuration/argument-data.html#using-a-custom-callback

Also if you need to update the option from outside of Redux (say on WooCommerce update of that value) you can set it this way:
https://docs.redux.io/guides/advanced-updating-an-option-manually.html